# Swapping videos on YouTube

Tags: youtube

I have some videos on YouTube with a series of views that I do not want to miss but that are not in the quality I want. I am improving some videos with the intention of changing some already existing in the site.

The question is: **Can I change these videos without losing my views?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't. You can use the built-in features of the platform such as adding cards or applying 'Enhancements' (Youtube's terminology, not mine), but there's no way to replace the video itself. From the [official documentation](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/55770):

> You can’t replace a video because any new video you upload to YouTube
>   will get a new URL. Instead, you can make changes to an existing
>   video:
>
> - **Enhance your video:** You can make some editorial changes to the video using YouTube Video Enhancements. You can trim parts of your
>     video, auto-fix lighting and color, blur parts of the video, apply a
>     filter, and more.
> - **Add cards to your video:** You can use cards to change elements of your videos. You can point viewers to a specific URL (from a list of
>     eligible sites) and show customized images, titles, and calls to
>     action, depending on the card type.
> - **Change your video's title and description:** You can organize and make changes to your video's title, category, description, and privacy
>     settings.

If video replacement is a feature you deem necessary for whatever content you are producing, you might consider switching to a hosting platform that allows you to do this. For example, replacing the original video file while keeping views, comments et c. intact is possible on [Vimeo](https://help.vimeo.com/hc/en-us/articles/224818047-Video-settings-overview) ([documentation](https://help.vimeo.com/hc/en-us/articles/224818047-Video-settings-overview), as of August 2017).

Comment: I already imagined that it would not be possible. But the idea of Vimeo is feasible.

Comment: The part of the question "not the quality you want" is open as to what would constitute a 'repair'. I believe that YouTube's Editor allows you to add new Music, crop the ends of the Video, apply Filters (gimmicky coloring) or Stabilize the Video AND save the new copy over the old one, thus preserving the views. I'd test it with a short "Private" upload to determine if it has the ability still, or if they've changed the Editor.